# Any idea how can i retrieve dates that belong to the week before from today's date?

Tags: sql, postgresql, date

I have a table "dates" with ids and dates: (the dates are in timestamp)

```
id start_date
1  2020-11-23 11:00:00
2  2020-11-23 12:00:00
3  2020-11-15 10:00:00
4  2020-11-24 09:00:00
5  2020-11-11 09:00:00
6  2020-11-24 13:00:00
7  2020-11-25 15:00:00
```

the code should return ids:

```
id
 1
 2
 4
 6
 7
```

i tried the following:

```
select id
from dates
where dates.start_date > DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(NOW())+6 DAY) 
AND dates.start_date <= DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(NOW())-1 DAY)
```

but it didn't seem to work. I'm having a syntax error:

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "DAYOFWEEK"

Consider today's date: 2020-11-26
I'm also using PostgreSQL!

Comment: Where [in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html) did you find the functions `date_sub()` and `dayofweek()`?

Comment: When you say from the week before, do you mean 1 week before now, the previous monday to sunday period or the previous sunday to saturday period? Some countries start counting the week at sunday, some at monday, and I think some at other days.

Comment: 1 week from now

Comment: i found the functions here on stack overflow because someone asked the same question and this was the answer given

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to want:

```
select id
from t
where t.start_date > current_date - interval '7 day';
```

Or, perhaps -- depending on how you define "week":

```
where t.start_date >= date_trunc('week', current_date) - interval '7 day' and
      t.start_date < date_trunc('week', current_date)
```